# How to disable this icon

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IContextualMenuProps, IIconProps, Stack, IStackStyles } from '@fluentui/react';
import { CommandBarButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';

export interface IButtonExampleProps {
  // These are set based on the toggles shown above the examples (not needed in real code)
  disabled?: boolean;
  checked?: boolean;
}

const menuProps: IContextualMenuProps = {
  items: [
    {
      key: 'emailMessage',
      text: 'Email message',
      iconProps: { iconName: 'Mail' },
    },
    {
      key: 'calendarEvent',
      text: 'Calendar event',
      iconProps: { iconName: 'Calendar' },
    },
  ],
};
const addIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'Add' };
const mailIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'Mail' };
const stackStyles: Partial<IStackStyles> = { root: { height: 44 } };

export const ButtonCommandBarExample: React.FunctionComponent<IButtonExampleProps> = props => {
  const { disabled, checked } = props;

  // Here we use a Stack to simulate a command bar.
  // The real CommandBar control also uses CommandBarButtons internally.
  return (
    <Stack horizontal styles={stackStyles}>
      <CommandBarButton
        iconProps={addIcon}
        text="New item"
        // Set split=true to render a SplitButton instead of a regular button with a menu
        // split={true}
        menuProps={menuProps}
        disabled={disabled}
        checked={checked}
      />
      <CommandBarButton iconProps={mailIcon} text="Send mail" disabled={disabled} checked={checked} />
    </Stack>
  )
};
```

[image]

How to disable this icon
in fluent-ui button component

which props or method
i need to add to disable it.
can anyone help regarding it
as i am not able to
get into fluent ui react
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/button

Comment: You are using `menuProps` that's why the icon is displayed. So use a fluentUI button without `menuProps` if you require only the button without sub-items.

Comment: I am requiring button with sub items not want that icon to be displayed

Comment: does the answer provide the info what you need?

Comment: @kartikaydwivedi Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71203965/how-to-remove-chevron-icon-when-providing-menuprops-for-a-fluentui-iconbutton-co/71205757#71205757

Answer (score 1):

You can specific the `menuIconProps` (read [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/button)) which will not display the icon if specified as empty string.

Add this property
`menuIconProps={{iconName: ""}}`

```
<CommandBarButton
        iconProps={addIcon}
        text="New item"
        // Set split=true to render a SplitButton instead of a regular button with a menu
        // split={true}
        menuIconProps={{iconName: ""}}
        menuProps={menuProps}
        disabled={disabled}
        checked={checked}
      />
```

With above change, the button will be displayed as shown below:

[image]